# Finding a Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

> Find the Fourier series $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{inx}$ of $f$, which is a $2\pi$-periodic function such that $$f(x) = |x|\quad \text{ for }\space x\in [-\pi, \pi].$$

I know how one typically goes about finding a Fourier series using the definition, but I'm unsure how to treat this. Would I take separate integrals for $[-\pi, 0]$ and $[0, \pi]$ so that we use $f(x) = -x$ in the integral from $-\pi$ to $0$ and $f(x) = x$ for the integral from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: Yes, you would, because that is the piecewise definition of |x|

Comment: You could use the fact that $f$ is even to reduce computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target function:
$$
 f(x) = |x| = 
\begin{cases}
  \phantom{-}x & x\ge 0 \\
 -x & x< 0
\end{cases}
$$

Since the function is *even* $f(x)=f(-x)$, it will be a cosine series. The Fourier amplitudes are
$$
\begin{align}
%
 a_{0} &= \frac{1}{\pi}\left( \int_{-\pi }^0 -x \, dx+\int_0^{\pi } x \, dx \right) = \pi \\
%
 a_{k} &= \frac{1}{\pi}\left( \int_{-\pi }^0 -x\cos(kx) \, dx+\int_0^{\pi } x \cos \left( kx \right) \, dx \right) = \frac{2 \left((-1)^k-1\right)}{\pi  k^2}\\
%
\end{align}
$$
The first few terms are
$$
\begin{array}{cr
}
 k & a_{k} \\\hline
 1 & -\frac{4}{\pi } \\
 2 & 0 \\
 3 & -\frac{4}{9 \pi } \\
 4 & 0 \\
 5 & -\frac{4}{25 \pi } \\
\end{array}
$$

[image: amps]

The convergence of the approximation is painfully slow:

[image: 1]
[image: 10]
[image: 100]
[image: 1000]

Comment: Wow, this is incredible - thank you! Just a quick question: while the function is even, and thus a cosine series, would we come to the same result using the general $e^{-inx}$, and if so, is this always the case?